# two different foreign keys on one model

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

I have these 3 tables

**products**

- id
- product_type_id
- name

**product_attributes**

- id
- product_type_id
- name

**product_attribute_values**

- id
- attribute_id
- product_id
- value

---

1. **Products** have multiple **attributes**, they are related by **product_type**
2. **Attributes** have multiple **attribute values**, they are related by **attribute_id**
3. **Attribute values** are related to one **attribute** and one **product**, they are related to the product by **product_id**

---

I have created 3 models, Product, ProductAttribute and ProductAttributeValue

**Product Model**

```
public function attributes(){  
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductAttribute', 'product_type_id',   'product_type_id');
}
```

**Product Attribute Model**

```
public function attributeValues(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductAttributeValue', 'attribute_id', 'id');
}
```

---

And then when im trying to get a product with all related attributes and attribute values

```
$product = Product::find(1)->with('attributes.attributeValues')->get()->toArray();
```

All of the attribute values for that attribute are being pulled in.

The problem is im not sure how to have 2 foreign keys to two different models...

I hope I explained it well enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = Product::where([
            ['id', '=', $category['id']],
            ['slug', '=', $productSlug]
           ])
           ->with(['attributes.values' => function ($query) {
           $query->where('product_id', '=', 1);
        }])->get()->first();
```

Comment: This is my solution.. Hope it helps someone.